# How to make ldconfig aware of custom shared library in OpenShift?

Tags: shared-libraries, openshift

The python module I use for deducting shared libraries paths is based on `/sbin/ldconfig` tool. More or less it prints system's libraries with `ldconfig -p` and uses the obtained list to find requested library. This tool is very convenient, thus I would like to use it for searching my custom installed libraries as well.

Issue is that without admin privileges I am not able to update `ldconfig` cache. I tried updating `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but it doesn't help - `ldconfig` still does not contain information about my library. I keep my libraries somewhere below `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`.

Obviously, as a regular user I am not able to put my library to any directory such as `/usr/lib`, that is taken into account by `ldconfig`.

So, the question is: is there a way to make `ldconfig` aware about the custom location that I keep my library in?

Comment: i am facing also the same problem :/